# Tableau server in VPCa pulling data from RDS in vpcB

Tags: amazon-web-services

Tableau server in vpca accessing RDS database in vpcb via jdbc/odbc connection can this be through vpc endpoint OR This has to be through Transit gateway or vpc peering.
I was not sure if this interface endpoint private link can be established for direct RDS access which is in a different vpc.

Thanks